# What's the best way to edit (also add and delete) array data in the SS CMS?

Tags: php, content-management-system, silverstripe

I am trying to get a gridfield to display an array of data, instead of a SS_List of DataObjects. So I decode a JSON string to create an array of class instances and would like to show a (few) fields of those objects in the rows of the gridfield. I am not using ordinary DataObjects to prevent versioned relations to get out of sync, so I JSON the related data on the parent object.

If there is an easier solution than a gridfield: I'm all ears!
So, how can I load a gridfield up with (array) data for it's rows? Or, what's the best way to edit (also add and delete) array data in the SS CMS?

Reading through the source and API didn't get me far, so that's why I ask you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an `ArrayList` containing `ArrayData` entries you should have some luck. ArrayList implements SS_List, and you should just disable any components that involve edit, add, remove etc via your GridFieldConfig (or just use an empty one to start with).

```
$myList = ArrayList::create();
foreach ($yourData as $values) {
    $myList->push(ArrayData::create($values));
}

$gridField = GridField::create('MyGrid', null, $myList, GridFieldConfig_Base::create());
```